# how to filter if label / value has been selected in react select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

how to filter if label / value has been selected in react select?

first I have a list of options (from the API) as follows:

```
const listFoodSelect = [
   {foodID: 123, label: 'food 1'},
   {foodID: 456, label: 'food 2'},
   {foodID: 789, label: 'food 3'},
   {foodID: 321, label: 'food 4'},
   {foodID: 234, label: 'food 5'}
];
```

Then I want if one of the labels / values that I have selected does not appear in the listFoodSelect, for example, I select foodID 234, how do I filter the list if the label / value has been selected?

expectations are as follows:

```
const listFoodSelect = [
   {foodID: 123, label: 'food 1'},
   {foodID: 456, label: 'food 2'},
   {foodID: 789, label: 'food 3'},
   {foodID: 321, label: 'food 4'},
];
```

this is a initial state

```
const [menuName, setMenuName] = useState('')
const [listFoodSelect, setListFoodSelect] = useState([])
```

This is a function to adjust if the value is selected

```
const onSelectMenu = (indexItem, indexFood) => event => {
    let { foodId, label } = event
    let data = [...listData]
    setMenuName(event.label)
    setListFoodSelect(listFoodSelect.filter(item => item.foodName !== label))
}
```

and this is the react-select component that has been returned

```
<Select
   onChange={onSelectMenu(indexItem, indexFood)}
   options={listFoodSelect.filter((option) => option.label !== menuName)}
   value={menuName}
/>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove all other options when the user selects an option?

Comment: no, I want if the user selects an option then only the selected option does not appear

Comment: so what's wrong with what you did?

Comment: the list options remain unfiltered

Comment: See my answer hope its what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

See this codesandbox I have created. Let me know if you have questions

https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-violet-yv5yt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thank you very much, this has started my expectations but something is missing, if the value is an array, how to filter it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `isMulti` prop. It allows you to select more than one item. Once an item is selected, it will be removed from the list of the select dropdown menu.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const listFoodOptions = [
    { value: 123, label: "food 1" },
    { value: 456, label: "food 2" },
    { value: 789, label: "food 3" },
    { value: 321, label: "food 4" },
    { value: 234, label: "food 5" }
  ];

  const [selectedFoods, setSelectedFoods] = useState([]);

  const handleSelect = (newlySelectedFoods) => {
    setSelectedFoods(newlySelectedFoods);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Select
        onChange={handleSelect}
        options={listFoodOptions}
        isMulti
        value={selectedFoods}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

When `isMulti` prop is used, the value will be an array of selected items.

See this code sandbox I have created.

https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-butterfly-vfxwi